# test in Nunjucks if a dict has key

Tags: nunjucks

Some of the test data have img some not.

I am new to Nunjucks and google does not find how to test if the record have key img?

I try the following:

```
{% for r in testdata %}
  {% if r.img %} <img src="{{img}}" alt="{{r.heading}}">{% endif %}
  ....
{% endfor $}
```

But seems does not work.

I have also search the Nunjucks doc, but does not find has_key or some other info.

```
testdata:
-
   type: G
   TID: 567
   heading: 泰國
   alt1: Tailânia
   source: 
-
   type: P
   TID: 4
   heading: Monteiro, Vicente
   alt1: 韋思明
   alt2: Monteiro, Vicente Joao
   source: 物業登記局局長 (1998)
-
   type: P
   TID: 1
   heading: Pires, Candida da Silva Antunes
   alt1: 李淑華
   source: 澳門大學法學院副教授, (1995)
   img: P0001.jpg
```

Comment: `{% if r.img %}` should work for `img` equals to `undefined`, `0`, `false` and empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now have another question : how do I test if the key is start with alt i.e., I would like to have alt1, alt2, alt3 to have the same format:

Comment: Thank you very much. I now have another question : how do I test if the key is start with alt i.e., I would like to have alt1, alt2, alt3 to have the same format:
  
   {% for n, v in r %) {% if n=="alt1" %}<p>&#x261D; {{v}}</p>{% endif %}{% if n=="alt2" %}<p>&#x261D; {{v}}</p>{% endif %}...{% endfor %}

That is not flexable if later there are more alternative names. If it is possible to test only the first 3 chars then it can be simple.

Comment: To test a key you can use `{% if n.substr(0, 3) eq 'alt' and Number.isInteger(+n.substring(3)) %} ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{% if r.img is defined %} should also do the trick. – Lesha Ogonkov 3 hours ago